# iOS AudioUnit settings to save mic input to raw PCM file

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, audiounit, pcm

I'm currently working on a VOIP project for iOS.
I use AudioUnits to get data from the mic and play sounds.
My main app is written in C# (Xamarin) and uses a C++ library for faster audio and codec processing.

To test the input/output result I'm currently testing recording & playback on the same device
- store the mic audio data in a buffer in the recordingCallback
- play the data from the buffer in the playbackCallback

That works as expected, the voice quality is good.

#### I need to save the incoming audio data from the mic to a raw PCM file.

I have done that, but the resulting file only contains some short "beep" signals.

#### So my question is:

What Audio settings do I need, that I can hear my voice (real audio signals) in the resulting raw PCM file  instead of short beep sounds?
Has anyone an idea what could be wrong or what I have to do that I'm able to replay the resulting PCM file correctly?

My current format settings are (C# code):

```cs
int framesPerPacket = 1;
int channelsPerFrame = 1;
int bitsPerChannel = 16;
int bytesPerFrame = bitsPerChannel / 8 * channelsPerFrame;
int bytesPerPacket = bytesPerFrame * framesPerPacket;
AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat = new AudioStreamBasicDescription ()
{
  SampleRate = 8000,
  Format = AudioFormatType.LinearPCM,
  FormatFlags = AudioFormatFlags.LinearPCMIsSignedInteger | AudioFormatFlags.LinearPCMIsPacked | AudioFormatFlags.LinearPCMIsAlignedHigh,
  BitsPerChannel = bitsPerChannel,
  ChannelsPerFrame = channelsPerFrame,
  BytesPerFrame = bytesPerFrame,
  FramesPerPacket = framesPerPacket,
  BytesPerPacket = bytesPerPacket,
  Reserved = 0
};
```

Additional C# settings (here in short without error checking):

```cs
AVAudioSession session = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();
NSError error = null;
session.SetCategory(AVAudioSession.CategoryPlayAndRecord, out error);
session.SetPreferredIOBufferDuration(Config.packetLength, out error);
session.SetPreferredSampleRate(Format.samplingRate,out error);
session.SetActive(true,out error);
```

My current recording callback in short (only for PCM file saving) (C++ code):

```cs
OSStatus 
NotSoAmazingAudioEngine::recordingCallback(void *inRefCon,
                              AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                              const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                              UInt32 inBusNumber,
                              UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                              AudioBufferList *ioData) {
std::pair<BufferData*, int> bufferInfo = _sendBuffer.getNextEmptyBufferList();
AudioBufferList* bufferList = new AudioBufferList();
bufferList->mNumberBuffers = 1;
bufferList->mBuffers[0].mData = NULL;
OSStatus status = AudioUnitRender(_instance->_audioUnit, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, inBusNumber, inNumberFrames, bufferList);
if(_instance->checkStatus(status))
{
    if(fout != NULL) //fout is a "FILE*"
    {
        fwrite(bufferList->mBuffers[0].mData, sizeof(short), bufferList->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize/sizeof(short), fout);
    }
}
delete bufferList;
return noErr;
```

}

Background info why I need a raw PCM file:

> To compress the audio data I'd like to use the Opus codec.
>   With the codec I have the problem that there is a tiny "tick" at the end of each frame:
>   With a frame size of 60ms I nearly can't hear them, at 20ms its annoying, at 10 ms frame sizes my own voice can't be heared because of the ticking (for the VOIP application I try to get 10ms frames).
>
> I don't encode & decode in the callback functions (I encode/decode the data in the functions which I use to transfer audio data from the "micbuffer" to the "playbuffer").
>   And everytime the playbackCallback wants to play some data, there is a frame in my buffer.
>
> I also eliminate my Opus encoding/decoding functions as error source, because if I read PCM data from a raw PCM file, encode & decode it afterwards, and save it to a new raw PCM file, the ticking does not appear (if I play the result file with "Softe Audio Tools", the output file audio is OK).
>
> To find out what causes the ticking, I'd like to save the raw PCM data from the mic to a file to make further investigations on that issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution myself:
My PCM player expected 44100 Hz stereo, but my file only had 8000 Hz mono and therefore my saved file was played about 10x too fast.